# Spring boot and postgresql: weird error while executing import.sql file

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application where I use Spring Data JPA with PostgreSQL as the database. I'm letting hibernate create the schema and that is working perfectly, but when I'm trying to populate the database with the import.sql file, an error shows up.
This is the error:

```
CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "insert into users(user_id, username, email, password, created_at)" via JDBC Statement
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input.
```

This is my import.sql file:

```
insert into users(user_id, username, email, password, created_at)
values(1, 'alex', 'alex@email.com', 'pword', current_timestamp);
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/website
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.datasource.username=alexander
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# drop n create table again, good for testing, comment this in production
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
# spring.sql.init.data-locations= classpath:/data.sql
# spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
# spring.sql.init.mode=always
# spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

The commented out part in application.properties are things that I've found in other threads that I've tried but with no change in result.

Every table gets created perfectly, and if I copy the contents of import.sql and inserts it into PostgreSQL via the terminal or pgadmin, then it works perfectly and the user gets inserted with 0 problems. So I really don't get what this "syntax error at end of input." could be.

PS. It's not an issue with the word current_timestamp either, if I swap it with for example ('2020-05-06 08:30') I still get the exact same error.

Comment: Have you tried putting the statement on a single line? It looks like it may be delimiting on new lines rather than semicolons.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thanks, this was actually the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have better solution for this problem than moving SQL insert into one line. Just add jpa property in application.properties which allows you to put SQL statements in multiple lines:

```
jpa:
  properties:
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
```

Having SQL insert statement in two (or multiple) rows can improve readability